# Get data from server after ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to submit data to the server using an ajax post request and then get data back into my web page as a response from the server.

In the code shown here I am intending that the ajax post request will result in the $arr array being sent to the web page as a JSON string. In fact the section of code inside the `if($_SERVER['RE...==='POST'){` conditional makes no difference to the outcome of clicking the button. If I delete it, I get the same result.

```
<?php
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

        // ajax handler
        $arr = ['profile' => 'Information about Fred',];
        echo json_encode($arr);
        exit();

    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Fred <button data-person='Fred'>Post Data</button>
        </p>
        <script>
            const button = document.querySelector('button');
            button.addEventListener('click', function(){
                const body = JSON.stringify({person: button.dataset.person});
                fetch(
                    './',
                    {
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} // Added in response to comment
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: body
                    }
                )
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the 'Post Data' button, I get the following in my browser console:

`Response { type: "basic", url: "https://stevespages.org.uk/sandbox/ajaxpost/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers(8), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }`.

I have no idea what the response represents. I was hoping it would contain `['profile' => 'Information about Fred',]` somewhere within it (on the browser console you can drill into the response to get more information) but I can not find it.

Comment: Try adding: **headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},** before method or body.

Comment: @imvain2 unfortunately that does not change anything.

Comment: Trying chaining to json(): `fetch(/* stff here */).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => console.log(data));`

Comment: @ChrisHaas That has sorted it out. Thanks!